# How to consume a soap web service using workbench?

Tags: webservices, soap, workbench

I would like to call a SOAP web service created in salesforce, **using Workbench**. There are some samples for other types of web services from the apex workbook but not for SOAP :-(

My class contains 2 methods, each one containing an argument.
Here is my code :

---

```
global class WsMyWebServiceClass {

...

webservice static List<Account>  getAccount(Integer  days) {
_________________________
```

How can I test my method from Workbench ?

When I log in Workbench, I select *Utilities | Rest Explorer*

**Get** is selected by default

```
/services/data/v36.0 is prefilled
```

If I type `/services/Soap/class/WsMyWebServiceClass` and click on Execute, I get the following message :

> GET not supported, this is a SOAP service, please use POST

So when I switch to **Post**, there is a Request Body that appears and I don't know what to fill in it ? Some JSON ?

When do I indicate that I'm using the getAccount method ?

If I use Post method, what do I need to fill for the 2 fields ?

`/services/Soap/class/WsMyWebServiceClass`... ?????
Request body ?

[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to use workbench? Or you want to test the service you have built?

Comment: I know how to do that with SOAPUI tool (so I tested my WS with success). But I would like to understand how it could work with Workbench.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is how I have tried using workbench to test a SOAP web service. Hope this helps.

First you have to get the session ID by passing a Soap request(I copied the request XML from SoapUI) to login method of the Salesforce SOAP API.

Service URL: `/services/Soap/u/37.0`

Method : `Post`

Request Headers: (below)

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/xml
SOAPAction: ''
```

Soap Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <urn:CallOptions>
         <urn:client></urn:client>
         <urn:defaultNamespace></urn:defaultNamespace>
      </urn:CallOptions>
      <urn:LoginScopeHeader>
         <urn:organizationId></urn:organizationId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:portalId></urn:portalId>
      </urn:LoginScopeHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:login>
         <urn:username>****************</urn:username>
         <urn:password>****password+security token****</urn:password>
      </urn:login>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Execute it you will get the webservice response.

In the response you will get the session ID. Copy it and keep it in your notepad to call your Apex webservice.

[image]

For next call you have to use the following details.

Service URL: `/services/Soap/class/sarojkbera/MyWebService` (MyWebService is the Apex class exposed as Soap service)

Apex Class:

```
global class MyWebService {
    webService static String makeContact(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return 'Hello '+firstName+' ' +lastName;
    }
}
```

Method : `Post`

Request Headers: (below)

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Accept: text/xml
SOAPAction: ''
```

Soap Request:

Here I have used the generated Soap request from SoapUI.

*Put the session ID (obtained in the previous step) in the request XML.*

Execute it and you will get the Webservice response as below.

[image]

Comment: I have the following error message when I try to get the session Id <sf:exceptionCode>INVALID_LOGIN</sf:exceptionCode><sf:exceptionMessage>Login is restricted through MyDomain url only. </sf:exceptionMessage></sf:LoginFault></detail></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Comment: As you said, I have no problem using the enterpise.wsdl to get my sessionId using SOAPUI. When I paste exactly the same request in Workbench, I got this error :  Login is restricted through MyDomain url only

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your detailed answer.

I can get the sessionId from SOAPUi or from Developer Console : system.debug(UserInfo.getSessionId()); So this is not a problem.

But I followed your advice for my web service :
Method : **POST**

**/services/Soap/class/MyWebService**

**Request Header :**
As indicated by Saroj

**Request Body :**
[image]